# Can't insert into SQL Server table with log4net AdoNetAppender

Tags: sql-server, log4net

I am trying to understand how log4net works so I've added this to my `app.config` (I should add that Console Appender and FileAppender work perfectly, I only have trouble with the AdoNetAppender).

How can I debug this, to see if at least the connection to db succeeds?

The problem is the INSERT statement isn't executed. 
I should add the

```
Data Source=MyWorkgroup\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyNewDatabase;User ID=juan;password=juan,
```

works perfectly when I try to connect to SQL Server manually, so not sure if that's the problem.

Also, the `ConnectionType` was taken from the official site:
https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.ConnectionType.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" 
                 type="log4net.Config.log4netConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="AdoNetAppender" 
                  type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
            <bufferSize value="10" />
            <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <connectionString value="Data Source=MyWorkgroup\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyNewDatabase;User ID=juan;Password=juan;Pooling=False" />
            <commandText value="INSERT INTO Logs([logDate],[logThread],[logMessage]) VALUES(getdate(),'1','1')" />
            <commandType value="Text" />
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="DEBUG"/>
            <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
        </root>
    </log4net>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Later edit (after using the debug method recommended by David):

haacked.com is indeed extremely interesting, great tip! However, it seems that it's describing what I'm instructing log4net to log, but not the result of those actions(?), if I'm reading this well (no failed/or succeeded?)
e.g.

> log4net: Setting Property [ConnectionType] to String value
>   [System.Data.SqlClien t.SqlConnection, System.Data,
>   Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToke n=b77a5c561934e089]
>   log4net: Setting Property [ConnectionString] to String value [Data
>   Source=MyWorkgroup\SQLEXPRESS;                         Initial
>   Catalog=MyNewDatabase;
>                         User ID=juan;                         Password=juan;
>                      Pooling=False] log4net: Setting Property [CommandText] to String value [INSERT INTO Logs([logDate],[logThread],[logMessage]) VALUES(getdate(),'1','1')] log4net:
>   Setting Property [CommandType] to CommandType value [Text] log4net:
>   Created Appender [AdoNetAppender] log4net: Adding appender named
>   [AdoNetAppender] to logger [root]. log4net: Hierarchy Threshold []

Piece of code that helped me obtain this info (in case the site should become unavailable) is:

```
  <appSettings>    
      <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
 </appSettings>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add
          name="textWriterTraceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="C:\temp\log4netdiagn.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Take a look at the following post for a desciption of how to enable the internal debugging output for `log4net`: http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/  Any time I have had difficulties getting a `log4net` configuration working properly (usually it is `AdoNetAppender` that I have to struggle with) it has been easy-to-fix as soon as I review the output from this 'internal debugging' from `log4net` to learn what is the true source of the problem.

Comment: Can you show us the structure for your `logs` table?  If you used the examples directly from the `log4net` site for the `logs` table structure, then there are additional columns that are *NON-Nullable* meaning that the `INSERT` statement shown in your config will never work.  Have you tried to execute that SQL `INSERT INTO Logs([logDate],[logThread],[logMessage]) VALUES(getdate(),'1','1')` directly in SSMS?  Does it work or does it error?

Comment: Thank you! I plan to add parameters once I get this to work. David, yes indeed that does work when executed directly in SSMS. I used the examples from Timothy Corey's video tutorial. I'm probably missing something. 
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Logs](
 [logDate] [datetime] NULL,
 [logThread] [varchar](250) NULL,
 [logMessage] [varchar](550) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO`

Comment: I've added an update to the original post. Wondering if there is a way for the internal debugging to highlight when/which action suceeds/fails, apart from briefly describing the course of action taken (as it seems it's doing).

Comment: Very silly, but of course it wasn't working because I had added `<bufferSize value="10" />` so the whole thing was waiting to fill the buffer before actually writing to the database. I've enjoyed working with internal debugger. Thanks for teaching me something new! PS I've run the same with bogus password for a test and the internal debugger reacts to it.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you figured it out.  Welcome to StackOverflow -- #SOReadyToHelp